# PHP syntax for Mongo $set order statement

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, set

I am attempting to update multiple array elements using a PHP version of the query described in [how to update sequence number in mongodb safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566847/how-to-update-sequence-number-in-mongodb-safely)

Which describes the query:

```
db.so.update(
{ _id: new ObjectId("4f55e7ba362e2f2a734c92f8")},
{ $set : { 'subs.1.order' : 3, 'subs.2.order' : 2 } }
);
```

I'm building a query to add an 'order' field to my document

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5209acfd0de2316335000001"
},
"bookListId": "116ad5af-7cc6-4652-9bb3-aea852e584e8",
"favoriteBook": [
    {
        "title": "One Favorite Book",
    },
    {
        "title": "Another Favorite Book",
    },
    {
        "title": "A Third Favorite Book",
    }
]
}
```

..and am doing it in PHP with

```
$criteria = array('bookListId' => $bookListId);

$favoriteBookOrder = array();

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($order);$i++) {
    $key = 'favoriteBook.'.($i+1).'.order';
    $val = $order[$i];
    $favoriteBookOrder[] = array($key=>intval($val));
}

$setFavoriteBookOrder = array('$set' => $favoriteBookOrder);
$collection->update($criteria, $setFavoriteBookOrder);
```

but this doesn't produce any result because the query doesn't have the correct organization of arrays..

```
error_log(json_encode($setupdated));
```

outputs

```
{"$set":[{"favoriteBook.1.order":2},{"favoriteBook.2.order":1},{"favoriteBook.3.order":3}]}
```

which if you notice has too many quotes, brackets around the entire array, and curly braces around each item.  I believe this is what is causing the error:

```
"Invalid modifier specified: $set"
```

What is the correct syntax for building the array in PHP?  Thanks!

**EDIT**

this is the fix

```
$favoriteBookOrder[] = array($key=>intval($val));

should be 

$favoriteBookOrder[$key] = intval($val);
```

also i removed the +1 from $i because Mongo indexes are 0 based

correct query now

```
{"$set":{"favoriteBook.0.order":1,"favoriteBook.1.order":2,"favoriteBook.2.order":3}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make you query work right you have to change one line:

```
 $favoriteBookOrder[] = array($key=>intval($val));
```

to

```
 $favoriteBookOrder[$key] = intval($val);
```

But I think you wont be happy with result, because it will something like this:

```
"favoriteBook" : {
    "0" : { "order" : NumberLong(123) },
    "1" : { "order" : NumberLong(321) },
    "2" : { "order" : NumberLong(456) }
}
```

I suggest you rewrite code in this way:

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($order);$i++)
    $favoriteBookOrder[$i]['order'] = $order[$i];

$setupdated = array('$set' => ['favoriteBookOrder' => $favoriteBookOrder]);
```

and you'll get:

```
"favoriteBookOrder" : [
    { "order" : NumberLong(123) },
    { "order" : NumberLong(321) },
    { "order" : NumberLong(456) }
]
```

P.S. you can play with `$pushAll` modificator instead of `$set`, it could be more suitable for you.